# Enter network credentials not working when connecting Win to Ubuntu Samba share

Tags: windows, samba, network-share, credentials

A real "Knacknuss"...

I have an Ubuntu Server, and setup Samba for Windows to connect. All is working fine but for that one particular Windows computer (Win 10 pro) that can not connect.

How can I get this one computer to also connect?

Ping is working.

For that one computer I keep getting the **Windows Security Enter network credentials** popup window. And it never logs on. I can't get passed that **Enter network credential** window. All other computers have no problem connecting.

[image: Windows Security Enter network credentials]

Things I tried:

I turned off the firewall.

Deleted Network Credentials.

Checked that the `hosts` file has nothing funny in it.

Checked Windows for corrupted system files.

I made sure that **SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support** in Windows Features is installed.

I also added a **DWORD** in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\AllowInsecureGuestAuth` of the value 1 to the registry, as suggested [here](https://www.techjunkie.com/windows-cannot-access-computer-error-0x80004005/#Quick_Fix_2_Check_NetBIOS).

Errors vary between the above, and occasionally this one

[image: Windows cannot access check the spelling of the name.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1125438/windows-10-password-error-with-samba-share), and it worked!

... my solution was to adjust the security policies on the Windows client.

Run > Secpol.msc

then I set Local Policies > Security Options > Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level to 'Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM & NTLM'
and the client connects just like before.

or

adding this in the share in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` will also fix it

```
ntlm auth = true
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: I think it helps establish what protocol to use for communication.